# Falsifiability of a hypothesis related to a gravitational geon at the edge of Solar System that I postulate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves, solar-system

This post is a version of a post with identificator Meta PSE **12909** that I've asked in recent past years on Meta Physics Stack Exchange [*Asking if the following post could be suitable for the main site Physics Stack Exchange.*](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12909/asking-if-the-following-post-could-be-suitable-for-the-main-site-physics-stack-e) These first paragraphs are edited verbatim from the post deleted by a moderator on MathOverflow with identifier [**418732**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418732/falsifiability-of-a-hypothesis-and-elements-of-mathematical-physics-about-a-nat) (closed last year and deleted, if I remember well because the genuine version isn't at research level, I don't add here my critic about the contect of physics that are being edited on MathOverflow and how this is received). My belief is that at the edge of our Solar System could exist a special region of space-time enjoying the feature that is stated in the hypothesis below. I add that this is a speculation that does'nt arise from the scientific method or knowledges (in fact, I am neither a physicist nor a scientist), if not through ideas of which I've persuaded myself.

**Hypothesis.** *Each body B having certain*$^{*}$ *mass becomes, when this body is placed in this special region* $R$ *(made of atoms of space and time) that I evoke at the edge of our Solar System, in a micro black hole which evaporates in its corresponding lapse of time, under the condition that the mass of the body* $B$ *satisfies the inequality* $$\text{Planck mass}\leq\operatorname{mass}(B)\leq\operatorname{mass}(\text{asteroid of 300,000 metric tons}).\tag{1}$$

*I evoke previous upper and lower limits for such quantity of mass (ordinary matter) for the body $B$ placed in this special region  but these upper and lower limits are unknown for my person: let's say that the mass of an apple or a cat, a pendulum or a prism, but also the mass of aircraft carrier, but neither the mass of a planetary body nor the mass correponding to a elementary particle.

> **Question.** A) Is falsifiable my hypothesis? B) I would like to know what's about the veracity of my hypothesis. What equations or knowledges can you propose with the purpose to discuss/contradict my claims/facts or consequences deduced under the assumption of previous hypothesis? **Many thanks.**

Wikipedia has the article [*Falsifiability.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) I can to add much more motivation about my speculations of certain unsolved problems in mathematics, history of discoveries, natural history of life and technology, diagrams... if I'm motivated to do it because I feel that  there is some respect to my post. These additional contributions/remarks will not be very original, because these are obvious. Meanwhile my hypothesis prevails, it will be never refuted.

With my humble knowledges what I evoke is a gravitational geon (a region of space-time in which the fundamental interactions electromagnetic interaction, the strong and weak interactions were destroyed by a natural event, and in such region, that revolves around the Sun, bodies of the mass, let's say multicellular organism or an Orion Spacecraft become in a micro black hole).

Comment: Some comments removed. Please refrain from off-topic discussions in comments that do not relate to the post being commented upon.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is *definitely* falsifiable. All you need to do is send a space probe to the edge of the solar system and see if it can still send signals. Voyager 1 is pretty far from the solar system - by many definitions it has left the solar system (and is still sending signals). But maybe your definition of the edge of the solar system is different. Also, a small handful of objects have entered and exited the solar system (like Oumuamua) - does your hypothesis allow things to enter from outside?

I'd say you hypothesis is very unlikely to be correct. I see, frankly, no reason whatsoever to think it's likely. Seems to be just an unmotivated wild idea. Usually (in physics at least, I cant speak for other fields) hypotheses are generated as natural extensions to existing ideas and theories. Usually they start with a model that explains previous observations, and that model has new implications that form a new hypothesis to be tested. Otherwise you are kind of making a "Russel's teapot"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot. It should be emphasized that Russel's teapot does not exist in our solar system. The analogy supports the idea that hypotheses should be well motivated before one feels the need to disprove them.

Although I would say neither your hypothesis nor Russel's teapot are properly unfalsifiable. As our ability to detect smaller objects improves, and we search the solar system for new objects, we should eventually find Russel's teapot if it exists. More importantly, one doesn't feel a compelling need to disprove the idea that there's a teapot orbiting the sun between the Earth and Mars until there has been some motivation to believe it's remotely likely. The same logic seems to apply to your idea.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention of my post, and your excellent answer. As soon I can to read and study your answer and link to Wikipedia, I could to add other comment, or consider to accept your answer, while I wait more feedback.

Comment: It is implicit that my hypothesis allow things to enter from outside, as I imagined it.

Comment: I'm going to read the full article from Wikipedia, but I see a (very subttle) problem in you argument, this is that **we have not traveled or explored, with astronauts, our Solar System nor do we know if there was a remote disaster in our Solar System**, in contrast to all the discoveries of the cosmos and all the natural history and science of the cosmos. I must necessarily accept your argument that a person who proposes an idea that seems strange/odd should give extraordinary evidence (as is quoted by Carl Sagan).

Comment: It's not *known* that Russell's teapot doesn't exist in our solar system. We have no proof that it doesn't, but also, we have no reason to think that it does, so we default to thinking it probably doesn't. One may cite Occam's razor to explain why.

Comment: @user253751 would you like to bet on that? I'll give you 1000 to 1 odds. If it doesnt exist, you give me $1000, if it does, I give you a million. Consider why you aren't willing to take that bet - because the teapot is known to not exist.

Comment: Dear professors @user253751 and the owner of this answer, which it is sure is that at that date there are thoushands of rockets with nuclear weapons on our Planet Earth. What animal species does such a thing? Occam's razor should be quoted to say that these weapons are actually propellants for exploring our solar system. We were always explorers. Didn't the pioneers of particle physics take risks to observe energetic phenomena in our atmosphere? Physicists will never get a TOE of Nature from a university office or a lab, it's not a curse that I invoke, it's  a conflict physicists don't see

Comment: @AndrewChristensen it is **unlikely** to exist simply because there is no known reason it should exist and it does not exist by default. This is not the same as saying it definitely doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @user253751 my argument against the argument of the professor who owns the answer, Russell's teapot, is that our Solar System is unexplored while that much science was deduced for the cosmos: this is a very strange story. Biological dispersal occurs (similar dispersals as refers the Wikipedia *Oceanic dispersal*) when volcanic eruption creates a new island, and in the remote past it occurs with continents. Travel to a continent and the most of the cells in the human body are replaced with atoms of such continent is a versatility or functionality that is not entirely obvious for me.